# What purpose could a domestic robot serve on a caravan?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

So, about 500 years after the apocalypse, a small trading company which makes the rounds from Den, Colorado to Vegas Nevada. They make about $20,000 a year, but times are getting tough. Then they find something precious in the wasteland, a functioning android from the bygone days, just wandering out in the desert. It’s not circuit broken (meaning it’s computer brain isn’t corrupted). So, they ask it what tasks could help them with their profession. Remember, it’s a domestic robot, designed to do common tasks at the home. So, what skills that a domestic android is mostly likely programmed with would be helpful in the trading business?

Comment: How strong is it? How good is it at memorizing details like budgets, deals, etc?

Comment: @Dan Clarke: it has a decent amount of memory space. 5 years of it

Comment: Note that "$20,000 a year" is meaningless in this context.  And I'm at a loss why the android can't simply do what it's designed for - domestic chores.  It is presumably trainable to some extent to learn the specific chores required.  "Domestic chores" would require flexibility - i.e. the ability to learn different tasks, even if they're relatively simple tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Postapocalyptic, so they are probably trading in used/refurbished goods as well. The robot would be good and single-minded at cleaning/polishing stuff. It might be programmed to know the cleaning instructions. *(Scrub this with a stiff brush, wipe that with a soft tissue.)*
- The robot might know how salvaged stuff fits together. It might even be programmed to diagnose if stuff is broken or functional. *(Anecdote: When I was a child, we had some Lego and Playmobil toys. They went into my parent's attic. 30 years later we got them down again for the next generation, and it took **my** generation to come over to sort them out. Neither grandparents nor grandkids knew what fit where. We would go "oh, that's the mast top of the pirate ship.")*